# How to unlimit PHP Deployer composer memory?

Tags: composer-php, php-deployer

I am running PHP deployer for a magento application from a docker-compose.
The apache is inside a container and there is a memory limit for php. I have control on the Dockerfile, if needed.

Currently my issue is that when I run `dep deploy` it crashes:

```
$ dep deploy 
✈︎ Deploying master on main
✔ Executing task deploy:prepare
✔ Executing task deploy:lock
✔ Executing task deploy:release
✔ Executing task deploy:update_code
✔ Executing task deploy:shared
➤ Executing task deploy:vendors
✔ Executing task deploy:failed
✔ Executing task deploy:unlock

In Client.php line 103:
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  The command "cd /home/public_html/releases/20201214130007 && /usr/local/bin/composer install --verbose --prefer-dist --no-progress --no-interaction --no-dev --optimize-autoloader --no-suggest" failed.  
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  Exit Code: 255 (Unknown error)
```

If I run the composer line inside the container with the addition of unlimit of the memory, it works:

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/local/bin/composer install --verbose --prefer-dist --no-progress --no-interaction --no-dev --optimize-autoloader --no-suggest
```

I tried to force to force deployer to use to use composer this way, but it didn't work:

```
# in deployer.php:
set('composer', 'php -d memory_limit=-1  /usr/local/bin/composer');
```

I think that it is because it is not using the `composer` from the set when doing `deployer:vendors` as can be seen from the verbose log:

```
➤ Executing task deploy:vendors
[main] > if hash unzip 2>/dev/null; then echo 'true'; fi
[main] < true
[main] > if hash composer 2>/dev/null; then echo 'true'; fi
[main] < true
[main] > command -v 'composer' || which 'composer' || type -p 'composer'
[main] < /usr/local/bin/composer
[main] > cd /home/public_html/releases/20201214125356 && /usr/local/bin/composer install --verbose --prefer-dist --no-progress --no-interaction --no-dev --optimize-autoloader --no-suggest
```

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: Which version of Composer are you using? Running `composer install` usually does not need that much memory

Comment: I am running composer 1.10.18. I tried with composer 2.0.8 but it is not compatible with my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the composer binary used by deployer, you need to set `bin/composer`, so change this

```
set('composer', 'php -d memory_limit=-1  /usr/local/bin/composer');
```

to this

```
set('bin/composer', 'php -d memory_limit=-1  /usr/local/bin/composer');
```